# Adding an intent filter for the default mail app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I've added this intent filter

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

My app shows up as a target for the intent in the chooser for many apps but not for the default mail application which is my main focus.  In other words, if I open the BBC news app, for example, select some text and choose Share, my app is listed as an option.  If I do the same from the mail app, it's not shown.  I also tried text/* for the mimeType.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

When you add the intent filter `android.intent.action.SEND` you are saying that "I can also handle such actions", as the mail-program, messaging, facebook and so on.

The mail program does not send such an intent with the SEND action, hence you cannot share anything from the mail app.

What are you trying to achieve ?